# Mysql group by dates in weekends

Tags: mysql

I have the next database:

[image: database]

What I want to get is the name of the city, and the number of tours grouped by weekends

I was trying to do something like this

```
select `cities`.`name`, 
SUM( CASE DAYOFWEEK(DATE(date)) WHEN 7 OR 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS TOURS
from `cities` 
left join `tours` on `cities`.`id` = `tours`.`city_id`
group by `cities`.`name`;
```

So if I have tours on the dates 2019/03/02 (Saturday), 2019/03/03 (Sunday) in the city X I would return X and 1 tour, as it groups the dates by the weekend. and if it had the dates 2019/03/09, 2019/03/10, I would return the Name of city X and 2 tours, since it has the dates of 2 and 3 as 1; and 9 and 10 as another tour.

the query I did only counts on Saturday and Sunday without distinguishing between different weeks.

Any idea?

### UPDATE

---

I have added a fiddle
[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p67a2heVvrysk1QSYdFjC8/2)

The desired result is

```
| name        | TOURS |
| ----------- | ----- |
| Amatitlan   | 0     |
| Guatemala   | 3     |
| Villa Nueva | 1     |
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Added

```
count(distinct week(`tours`.`date`, 1))AS TOURS
```

And complete query

```
select `cities`.`name`, 
count(distinct week(`tours`.`date`, 1))AS TOURS
from `cities` 
left join `tours` on `cities`.`id` = `tours`.`city_id`
group by `cities`.`name`;
```

[fiddle with the desired result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p67a2heVvrysk1QSYdFjC8/4)

Answer (score -1):

if i understand correctly you want your count of tour  by different weeks only for weekend.

I think below is solution. correct me if i am wrong.

```
select `cities`.`name`, 
SUM( CASE DAYOFWEEK(DATE(date)) WHEN 7 OR 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS TOURS,
WEEKS(date),
from `cities` 
left join `tours` on `cities`.`id` = `tours`.`city_id`
group by `cities`.`name`,WEEKS(date);
```

Comment: `WEEKS` is not a valid MySQL function. I think you probably want `YEARWEEK`